# Azure deploy can't find my file in the project

Tags: azure

I've a resource file in my console project under `*root*/res/cosmo.pdf`.

The code for fetching the filepath in my application is:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\res\\cosmo.pdf"
```

When publishing the project to an azure web app as a webjob and running it I get the error:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\testclient\rhdistle.3og\res\cosmo.pdf'
```

Where should I place resource files so azure knows where to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\testclient\rhdistle.3og\res\cosmo.pdf'

Firstly, check if the pdf file has been publish to D:\home\site\wwwroot in KUDU.

With the pdf file missing, you could use **Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH");** to get the root path direcroty of webjob.

**WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH** which is location of webjob files, you can specify an absolute path, or otherwise the value will be combined with the default root path:

`D:/home/site/wwwroot/ + WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH(relative)` to the pdf you want.

For more detail, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#settingsjob-reference).

Comment: I found webjob under: D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered\viewpointprocoretestclient in KUDU but not the .pdf

Comment: Ok, now the file is uploaded to the webjob folder. I put an absolute path to the .pdf and now its working.