# export to excel working in local but not in server after deploying

Tags: excel, azure, c#-4.0

Look at below c# code as I running this code on the Local server it's working but after deploying in Azure it's not working.
Someone, please help me to resolve this issue

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ptoexport()
{
  string file = @"filepath";
  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
  ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
  ExcelWorksheet myWorksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
  myWorksheet.Cells[5, 5].Value = 34;
  p.Save();
  return Ok("Success");
}
```

Comment: What's the error?  What Azure service are you using?

Comment: error am getting after deployment in Azure while calling that ptoexport() function getting internal server error 500,we are using  ASP.NET WebApi 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I running this code on the Local server it's working but after deploying in Azure it's not working.

As I have tested, I think the file path you provided in code is your local xlsx file path. So when you run in local, the method could find the file, but when it publish to azure it failed.

So, I suggest that you could **upload file to KUDU** and **change the file path**.
I upload the xlsx file here and use the following, it works fine.
[image]

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ptoexport()
    {
        string file = @"D:/home/site/wwwroot/new.xlsx";
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
        ExcelWorksheet myWorksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        myWorksheet.Cells[5, 5].Value = 34;
        p.Save();
        return Ok("Success");
    }
```

Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458883/azure-deploy-cant-find-my-file-in-the-project/48460055#48460055) about why Azure deploy can't find file, you could also refer to it.